# Mongo parent sum wrong due to duplicates after child array unwind

Tags: mongodb

I have two sums to calculate in my Mongo schema. One is in the parent and the other is in the child array. When I unwind the child array I get duplicate objects that make the parent sum too large.

Here is the schema:

```
orders = [{ 
          orderDate: new Date(), 
          amt: 1000, 
          shipments: [{ shippedAmt: 200 }, { shippedAmt: 300 }]
     }, 
     {  
          orderDate: new Date(), 
          amt: 5000, 
          shipments: [{ shippedAmt: 1000 }, { shippedAmt: 2000 }]
     }
]
```

I just need to know how to project, group, unwind and project again to get grouping by month with amt total and also same grouping by month for shippedAmt total.

Comment: You want final ans to be **grouped** by `orderedDate` and **total sum** of `amt` for that date, and **total sum** of `shippedAmt` for that date?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, no need of unwinding or anything so cunsumer of resources her. 
You can do this in a single group stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {
          $year: "$orderDate",
        },
        month: {
          $month: "$orderDate",
        }
      },
      totalAmt: {
        $sum: "$amt"
      },
      totalShipments: {
        $sum: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$shipments",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $add: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this.shippedAmt"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Explanations : Group by year and month, sum Amt, and sum of reduced shipments array (reduce itself calculate the sum of shipments for each documents).

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fNPYq_zj1_k)

Comment: Thanks matthPen, your answer is quite clear and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query:

```
db.orders.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$orderDate",
    amtTotalOut: {
      $sum: "$amt"
    },
    shipments: {
      $push: "$shipments"
    }
  }
}, {
  $unwind: {
    path: "$shipments", preserveNullAndEmptyArray: true
  }
}, {
  $unwind: {
    path: "$shipments", preserveNullAndEmptyArray: true
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    amtTotalOut: {
      $first: "$amtTotalOut"
    },
    totalShippedAmt: {
      $sum: "$shipments.shippedAmt"
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Explanation:

First I grouped with `orderDate`, and calculated the sum of `amt`, using **`$sum`** accumulator in **`$group stage`**.

That way, we get _id to equal `orderDate`, and it will solve the duplicate entries of `amt` field and also eliminate the huge sum of `amt` due to duplicate entries.

In this stage I also pushed `shipments` to form an array of shipments, retaining all the values of the shipments field, but it makes shipments output from $group stage as *array inside and array*,

Hence, I used $unwind, twice on `shipments`,

and then in final **`$group stage`** again I used **`$sum`** to calculate the sum of `shippedAmt`.

**Update:**

In query I have used `orderDate` in $group stage, you can use **`$month and $year operators`** to group by month-year.

```
{$group: {
    _id: {
       month: { $month: "$orderDate"},
       year: { $year: "$orderDate"}
    }
}}
```

Comment: Really? Where is this grouped by month as asked?

Comment: ya, that part is not there in the query(actually it should be), but I don't think that is the **main issue** here, order by month can easily be done with $month operators (or giving search to docs/blogs), My query does solve the main problem of duplicate entries and gives correct answer . However, I will update my answer.

Comment: @matthPen But I did like your approach more... :-)